# enum class is not a class or namespace

Tags: c++, arrays, class, c++11, enums

I have a problem with the enum class feature of c++11. A minimal code example is:

```
template<typename T>
class AClass{
public: 
enum class paramNames{
    PA = 0,
    PB,
    PC,
    NUM
};

private:
double params[paramNames::NUM];
}
```

when I want to compile a program, which uses this program with gcc I get the following error message:

> error: 'paramNames' is not a class or namespace double params[paramNames::NUM];

I would appreciate, if someone can explain to me, how to use the new enum class feature correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike the old `enum` there is no implicit conversion to `int`. By design `enum class` cannot be converted to the underlying type implicitly. You can read more about the justification for that here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2347.pdf. To do what you want you need to use a static cast and do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class AClass{
public: 
enum class paramNames: int{//specify the underlying type
    PA = 0,
    PB,
    PC,
    NUM
};

private:
    double params[static_cast<int>(paramNames::NUM)];
}
```

EDIT: Make sure your compiler has the c++11 language features available to it, otherwise you will get errors doing this.

Comment: while you comment seems very useful, when I implement your code I still get the same error message:
 enum class paramNames: int{
                         ^
aclass.hpp:63:33: error: 'paramNames' is not a class or namespace
  double params[static_cast<int>(paramNames::NUM)];

Comment: What version of gcc are you using and what command line arguments are you giving to gcc? Make sure you have access to the c++11 language features via the option `-std=c++11`.

Comment: The compiler flag did the trick, despite it saying enabled by default in the warning. Thank you very much for the help.